# I expected ui:repeat would create table rows with columns, but it creates spans inside rows

Tags: jsf

I am using Primefaces p:datatable with p:rowExpansion. My aim was to show row details using following xhtml.

```
<p:dataTable
        value="#{bilisimArizaBean.kullaniciBilisimArizalariListesi}"
        var="ariza">
        <p:column style="width:4%">
            <p:rowToggler />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Arıza no">
#{ariza.bilisimArizaId}
</p:column>
        <p:column headerText="">
#{ariza.bilisimArizaTuru.bilisimArizaTuru}
</p:column>
        <p:column>
#{ariza.cihazMarkasi} #{ariza.cihazModeli} #{ariza.cihazSeriNo}
</p:column>
        <p:column>
#{ariza.arizaAciklama}
</p:column>
        <p:rowExpansion>
            <div>
                <p:panelGrid id="display" columns="4" cellpadding="4"
                    style="border:1px;border-color:red;"
                    styleClass=" ui-widget-content grid">
                    <ui:repeat var="ticket" value="#{ariza.bilisimArizaTicket}">
                        <h:outputText value="Gelişme No" />
                        <h:outputText id="gelisme" value="#{ticket.ticketAciklama}" />
                        <h:outputText value="Durum:" />
                        <h:outputText id="durum" value="#{ticket.arizaDurum.durumAdi}" />
                        <br></br>
                    </ui:repeat>
                </p:panelGrid>
            </div>
        </p:rowExpansion>
    </p:dataTable>
```

I expected it will create table rows with columns inside p:rowExpansion. But it,ui:repeat produces a table with rows with only one column. And spans inside this column. That is

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><span>data</span><span>data</span><span>data</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span>data</span><span>data</span><span>data</span></td>
</tr>
.
.
.
</table>
```

I expected and want the following

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>data</td>    <td>data</td>    <td>data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>data</td>    <td>data</td>    <td>data</td>
</tr>
.
.
.
</table>
```

Why spans instead of columns in this case? And how can get columns instead of spans in one columns?

Regards

Comment: I produced what I want by hardcoding html table. However I want to know reason for spans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your particular construct, the `<ui:repeat>` inside `<p:panelGrid>` doesn't generate multiple JSF components which generates its HTML each only once. Instead, it reuses the same JSF components to generate its HTML output multiple times on every iteration.

This is not right. You need a `<h:dataTable>` or `<p:dataTable>` here instead of `<p:panelGrid><ui:repeat>`.

E.g.

```
<h:dataTable var="ticket" value="#{ariza.bilisimArizaTicket}">
    <h:column><h:outputText value="Gelişme No" /></h:column>
    <h:column><h:outputText id="gelisme" value="#{ticket.ticketAciklama}" /></h:column>
    <h:column><h:outputText value="Durum:" /></h:column>
    <h:column><h:outputText id="durum" value="#{ticket.arizaDurum.durumAdi}" /></h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Those spans are unrelated, they are just coming from `<h:outputText>`.

Comment: Thanks Balusc, it seems i need to learn jsf principles in deep, any book advice?